# Tangent Bundle of $\mathbb{S}^{1}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, spheres, tangent-bundle

i would like to show  that the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{S}^{1}$ is diffeomorphic to a infinite cylinder $\mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{R}$. Well, the set of points $(p,v)\in T\mathbb{S}^{1}$ satisfies two equations: (i) $p_{1}^{2}+p_{2}^{2}=1$ and (ii) $p_{1}v_{1}+p_{2}v_{2}=1$, resolving this system in function of $(v_{1},v_{2})$ using the Cramer rule, i found that $v_1=-\lambda p_{2}$ and $v_{2}=\lambda p_{1}$, where $\lambda=\det \begin{bmatrix}
    q_{1}      & q_{2}  \\
    v_{1}       & v_{2} 
\end{bmatrix}$. Thus my candidate for diffeomorphism is $\phi: \mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{R} \to T\mathbb{S}^{1}$ such that $\phi(p,v)=(p,\lambda p^{t}$), where $p^{t}=(-p_{2},p_{1})$. I showed that $\phi$ is injective, smooth, but i don't know if this application is onto. Any tips?

My thinking is correct, how could I generalize it?

Comment: I don't understand, your proof seems pretty complete to me. You probably mean $v_1 = - \lambda p_2$. And the equation for the tangent line should be $p_1v_1 + p_2v_2 = 0$. Modulo these correction this looks perfectly fine. If you want to generalize, $T(X \times Y) \cong TX \times TY$ gives you $T(T^k) \cong \mathbb (R \times \mathbb S^1)^k \cong (\mathbb C^*)^k$.

Comment: Yes @N.H., $v_{1}=-\lambda p_{2}$ thanks. My problem is to find a point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(x,y)=(p,v)$, where $(p,v)$ in an arbitrary point in $T\mathbb{S}^{1}$. Resolving this equation i found that $x=p$ and $yp^t=v$, but how isolate the term $y$ in last equation?

Comment: You already know $x = p$. Since $\mathbb S^1 \ni p \neq 0$, your equation is $(-yp_2, yp_1) = (v_1, v_2)$. Since at least one coordinate (says $p_1$) is non zero, you get $y = v_2/p_1$.

Comment: Your proof is mistaken: when you write an arbitrary point of $T \Bbb S^1$ as $(p,v)$, you already assume that $T \Bbb S^1$ is trivial - but this is the most difficult part. Once you have this, it is not difficult to use a trivializing section to get the desired result.

Comment: @AlexM. : You are right, but the description of $TS^1$ given by the OP with equations is exactly the trivialisation he wanted, so I don't think it's mistaken.

Comment: @N.H.: Well, in order to get to those equations a trivialization is required in the first place, so... It seems to me that the OP assumes the most important part of what is to be proved, in which case there isn't much work left to do. It is not clear to me what the OP is allowed to take for granted (maybe this is just a homework problem with the main result having been proved in the lectures).

Comment: This is true, and I don't know how the tangent bundle was defined in his class. But for example, since $S^1$ is the zero set of $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1$, the tangent space is exactly $d_pf = 0$ which is the OP's equation. So I was thinking he did see that for hypersurface, tangent bundle coincide with the set $ \{ (x,u) \in \mathbb R^{2n} : f(x) = 0, df(u) = 0 \}$. But I agree once you have the equations there is not too much work to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is correct, here is a different proof which generalize more easily : a vector bundle $E \to M$ of rank $r$ is trivial if and only if there are sections $s_1, \dots, s_n : M \to E$ such that for all $m \in M$, $(s_1(m), \dots, s_r(m))$ is a basis of $E_m$.

In particular, since the tangent bundle of $S^1$ is of rank $1$, this is enough to find a non-vanishing tangent vector field, which you did find, given by $(x,y) \mapsto (-y,x)$. Same vector field works for $T^n = S^1 \times \dots \times S^1$ and gives you $T((S^1)^n) = (S^1)^n \times \mathbb R^n$.

Notice that by Poincaré-Hopf theorem, any manifold with non-zero Euler characteristic (for example $S^2$ since $\chi(S^2) = 2$) can't have $TM \cong M \times \mathbb R^n$ ($n = \dim M$) since any vector field will have at least a zero somewhere.